# Meaning of "I'm with the ..." construction

Tags: meaning, prepositions

As a non-native speaker of English, the construction "I'm with the ..." sounds a bit strange to me. I understand that it has about the same meaning as "I'm from the ...", as in "I'm with the police/IRS" and "I'm from the police/IRS", but I'm still concerned, where and how did this particular construction come from and does it differ in principle from the construction with "from"?

Comment: This entry of the OED hasn't been updated lately, but they have examples of "with" meaning in the service or employment of someone/something as far back as the 15th century. It's a pretty obvious extension from the meaning "in the company, society, or presence of".

Comment: Also note that neither "I'm with the police" nor "I'm from the police" [necessarily means you are a police officer](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/im-with-from-the-fbi.1381038/).

Comment: "I'm from the police" sounds wrong to me; I can't imagine a police officer saying that to someone. "I'm from the IRS" sounds fine, though. Hm...

Comment: As you are a non-native speaker I respectfully suggest that you should be posting to our subreddit sister site, English Language Learners. Before doing so I would ask you to finish reading the [Tour] to inform yourself of the scope and requirements of the site.

Answer (score 0):

> I’m with Google

may mean

> I’m employed by Google

or

> I agree with Google

or

> I’m accompanying representatives of Google

It would rarely be used in American English to mean

> I am officially representing Google

For that meaning, what would be more common is

> I’m from Google

The fields of meaning of “I’m with” and “I’m from” overlap but are not identical.